# How do I build a multi-input and multi-output neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow, multi-output

I want to build a neural network classifier which has as inputs array of dimension `(24, 2, 20001)` and as outputs array of dimension `(24, 7)`. I build a simple model using the following Python code:

```
print(np.shape(acfs))#(24, 2, 20001)
print(np.shape(ks)) #(24, 7)

#Build the model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(acfs, ks, test_size=0.05, shuffle=True, random_state=721)


dim1 = len(acfs[0])
dim2 = len(acfs[0][0])
           
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=12,input_shape=(2, 20001),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=7))
#number of nodes of the output layer has to be equal
#to the number of output variables.
print(model.summary())

#Compile the model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,  batch_size=128, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),verbose=2, epochs=15)
```

However, when I fit the model, the following `ValueError` arises:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 7 and 2 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](IteratorGetNext:1, Cast_1)' with input shapes: [?,7], [?,2].
```

I think I am missing something of important... I have never worked with multi-inputs and multi-output neural networks and in general I am new in this field.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks.